# Google Api .NET Library OAuth2 Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, google-api

I am attempting some experiments using the code samples provided near the bottom of the [page](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2)

Below are extracts of my VB.NET code based on the link above.
Somewhere in the translation I'm missing what is going on here:

```
Dim auth = New OAuth2Authenticator(Of NativeApplicationClient)(provider, GetAuthorization)
```

The GetAuthorization method has a signature:

```
GetAuthorization(arg As NativeApplicationClient)
```

I am clearly missing something very obvious about the syntax translation between C# and VB.NET, because there is no parameter supplied at the method call in the C# version on the link I supplied.

Comment: It would be easier if you just posted the C# code you are trying to translate rather than making us open a link and find it on another page.

Comment: A quick search on the google api .net client for oauth2, I found this page: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2 which shows usage using the OAuth2Authenticator. I think he's only trying to create a new object like they do in their example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must specify the `AddressOf` parameter to reference a method.

```
Dim auth = New OAuth2Authenticator(Of NativeApplicationClient)(provider, AddressOf GetAuthorization)
```

Comment: Thank you; there's apparently a lot I don't fully understand about delegates and .net